# Multiple websites on 1 VPS MVC

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, iis, vps, domain-name

Right now I'm using shared hosting for my websites and I'm not very satisfied with it. Someone recommended a VPS instead but I have no idea which one to pick.

I'm developing **ASP.NET MVC 3** sites and I have about 4 sites I need to host. I guess I should use IIS to host the sites but I'm a little bit confused.

Is it possible to point 1 domain name to each website I'm making? And what do I do if I want to send mail?

Example.

```
www.site1.com has some emails eg. info@site1.com

www.site2.com has some emails eg. info@site2.com
```

I guess I need a mail server? To be able to read and view my emails. like WorldClient

Comment: **Belongs to [serverfault.com](http://www.serverfault.com)**

Comment: BTW: Of course it's possible to point several domain names to a single IIS running several web applications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can any number of domains on one single server. When you create the site on IIS Manager, give the different domain names in the host name field and point the relevant domains to the directory.
2. For mail server I generally go for Apache James, but this is console based app so configuring this is a bit tedious. Smarter Mail is also another option on windows with full windows GUIs for configuring the mail servers.
3. The mail servers can be configured in your DNS settings. So your mail.domain.com will become your mail server.

Btw, both mail servers I mentioned give you options for POP access for reading from outlook express etc.,